# Get rid of the need for parenthesis in my unary operator

Tags: ios, swift, generics

**NOTE! ~ is just an example prefix, I will probably not use that later.**

I've made a function that can be used to instantiate a instance of a class and then set some attributes in the closure.

First I made it as a function, but now I want it as a operator.

The goal is to be able to write:

```
let view = ~UIView.self {
    $0.hidden = true
}
```

but with my current implementation I have to write:

```
let view = (~UIView.self) {
    $0.hidden = false
}
```

The code I have now for the operator is:

```
prefix operator ~ { }
prefix func ~<T: NSObject> (s: T.Type) -> ((_: (_:T) -> Void) -> T) {
    let o = T.init()
    return {
        $0(o)
        return o
    }
}
```

I've found out that I can change it to a postfix operator instead:

```
postfix operator ~ {  }
postfix func ~<T: NSObject> (_: T.Type) -> ((_: (_:T) -> Void) -> T) {
    let o = T.init()
    return {
        $0(o)
        return o
    }
}
```

And then it's fine to write:

```
UIView.self~ {
    $0.hidden = false
}
```

Though I'd prefer to have it solved for the prefix!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `prefix` instead of `infix`? Though the `~` prefix operator already exists (for bitwise operations) so there's no need to declare the operator at all here. It doesn't solve your parentheses problem, though.

Comment: Hmmm.. True. Actually, If I change it to a postfix operator instead, the problem is gone! :)